# How to omit the result after I get the result in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am writing a code using Linux. I used the 'until' function to find my file however I am unable to remove the result once I found it. Any guidance?

My code:

```
until find $filename
do
  echo "Please re-enter text file name:"
  read filename
done
```

Result:

```
Enter text file name: process.txt
process.txt <- need to remove this
```

Comment: @Rob & @ Lawrence Cherone Oops sorry, thank you for the head-up!

Comment: Rather than `find`, it would be a lot cleaner to write `until test -e "$filename"; do ...`.  Also, that would solve the problem, since the output you are seeing is coming from `find`

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! My lecturer didn't teach me all these at all so I need to learn this from the internet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are trying to discard is coming from `find`.  Either redirect it to /dev/null, or use:

```
until test -e "$filename"; do
        echo "Please re-enter text file name:"
        read filename
done
```